# How do I combine this two application class for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two application class which I want to combine in one, but provides two function, but I want it only one class so that I can call it on the application class in my manifest and get the App to produce both functions since i can not have two classes called on the application class in my manifest file in android studo.

I would like to put the AppController class in the App.Java class

Where I am confused is how to combine it since both extends different classes which java does not permit extending two classes in one.

Below is the App.java class

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication implements Constants {

    public static final String TAG = App.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static App mInstance;

    private ArrayList<Feeling> feelingsList;
    private ArrayList<BaseGift> giftsList;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    private String username, fullname, accessToken, gcmToken = "", fb_id = "", photoUrl, coverUrl, area = "", country = "", city = "";
    private Double lat = 0.000000, lng = 0.000000;
    private long id;
    private int state, allowRewardedAds = 1, admob = 1, ghost, pro, verify, balance, allowShowMyInfo, allowShowMyFriends, allowShowMyGallery, allowShowMyGifts, allowGalleryComments, allowComments, allowMessages, allowLikesGCM, allowCommentsGCM, allowFollowersGCM, allowGiftsGCM, allowMessagesGCM, allowCommentReplyGCM, errorCode, currentChatId = 0, notificationsCount = 0, messagesCount = 0, guestsCount = 0, newFriendsCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.settings_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        this.readData();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            try {

                ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

   // NB; I have some more codes in here which i am unable to put in full here.
    }
}
```

Then this this the second class AppController.java

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;
    private static String mAppUrl;
    public static MediaPlayer player;
    public static Activity currentActivity;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setContext(getApplicationContext());
        mAppUrl = Constant.PLAYSTORE_URL + mContext.getPackageName();
        setTelephoneListener();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayerInitializer();
        //AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    public static void mediaPlayerInitializer(){
        try {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(getAppContext(), R.raw.snd_bg);
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getAppUrl() {
        return mAppUrl;
    }
    private static void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    
    public static void playSound() 
    {
        try {
            if (SettingsPreferences.getMusicEnableDisable(mContext)&&!player.isPlaying()) {
                player.start();
            }else{
            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mediaPlayerInitializer();
            player.start();
        }
    }
    public static void StopSound() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.pause();
        }

    }
    
    private void setTelephoneListener() {
        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    StopSound();
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    StopSound();
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };

        TelephonyManager telephoneManager = (TelephonyManager) getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephoneManager != null) {
            telephoneManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
    static
    {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MulitdexApplication extends Application.
You could change your AppController to:

```
public class AppController extends MulitdexApplication
```

and then your App to

```
public class App extends AppController implements Constants
```

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant answer, once I do this, which of them should I call in application class?

Comment: I added this on my Manifest `android:name=".app.App."` application class after implementing this on my app, thank you so very much @Traendy you solved my problem. This should help always for anyone who might have similar problem related to this should.

Answer (score 1):

Just Extend Your "AppController" class to "App" class. No need to do extra other work.

Like Below.

```
public class AppController extends App {
......
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, am I to call the AppContoller or App class in my manifest file application  app:name=?

Comment: Yes, Just add AppController class in your manifest like app:name="AppController"